# Inverting the complex function $f(z)=z+\sqrt{z^2-2}$.

Tags: complex-analysis, inverse-function

I have the following complex valued function 
$$
f(z) = z + \sqrt{z^2 - 2}.
$$
I would like to find a function $g$ such that
$$
g(f(z)) = f(g(z)) = z
$$ 
on some domain of $\mathbb{C}$.

Comment: complex functions are usually not injective so this may not be possible at all

Comment: @AFalseName This map is injective though. One should clarify what is meant by $\sqrt{\cdot}$ in this context though; such a $g$ exist only on the subset of $\Bbb{C}$ where $z=\sqrt{z^2}$ and $z\neq0$.

Comment: @Servaes so in this case $\sqrt{i}=e^{i\pi/4}$ only and not the other root?

Comment: @AFalseName In this case no branch of $\sqrt{\cdot}$ is specified.

Answer (score 3):

**HINT:** Note that $f(z)^2=z^2+2z\sqrt{z^2-2}+z^2-2=2zf(z)-2$.

Answer (score 1):

$\begin{align} f(z) & = z+\sqrt{z^2-1} \\
(f(z)-z)^2 &= z^2-2 \\
f(z)^2 -2zf(z) + z^2 &= z^2-2 \\
-2zf(z) &= -2-f(z)^2 \\
z  &= \frac{2+f(z)^2}{2f(z)} \\
\end{align}$

In order to know wether a transformation I apply at each step is injective or not I think of complex numbers either in polar or cartesian coordinate.

$g(z)=\sqrt z$ appears injective (rotation + homothety) if picture it in polar coordinate for example. While $g(z) = z - 2$ appears injective (translation) if you picture it in cartesian coordinates.

Comment: I do not see how you get from the third to the fourth equation; the fourth does not hold. Beyond that your approach seems identical to what I suggested by my hint.

Comment: Yea I was pretty slow doing the computations and writing it in MathJax. Not slow enough since I still manage to make a mistake. I corrected it. I read your hint afterwards and it is pretty different I think. Nicer and more straightforward than the way I solve the problem.

Comment: Your last step is still off by a minus sign. My hint says that $f(z)^2=2zf(z)-2$ which immediately implies that $\frac{f(z)^2+2}{2f(z)}=z$, which is what your conclusion will be as well.

Comment: Yes right thanks ^^ I am definitely to slow for this